# How to find a file which ends with "/folder/subfolder/" in Mac OS X Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I would like to find a file which is located for example in `/Users/username/Library/folder/subfolder`. I know that last two subdirectories would be `/folder/subfolder` but I don't know in advance what the first part would be.

I was thinking something like `find */folder/subfolder/` but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the .../folder/subfolder/ folder itself, all files in it, or some specific file in it? For the folder itself:

```
find / -path "*/folder/subfolder" -type d
```

For all files in it:

```
find / -path "*/folder/subfolder/*"
```

For a specific file directly in the folder:

```
find / -path "*/folder/subfolder/filename"
```

For a specific file somewhere under it:

```
find / -path "*/folder/subfolder/*" -name "filename"
```

Comment: Looks promising, but It doesn't finds folder. If i use `find / -name "subfolder"` at least it finds correct folder. Any thoughts?

Comment: @markich: A couple of things come ti mind: Is capitalization different? If so, either use `-ipath` (case insensitive path match) or adjust the pattern (e.g. `-path "*/[Ff]older/[Ss]ubfolder"`). Also, make sure the path pattern starts with `*/`; if you're looking for the folder, do NOT put a slash at the end; if looking for a file inside, include it and something to match the filename (either the name or `/*`).

Answer (score 0):

Try `find / -name "*/?older/?ubfolder/*" -print`

That would, starting from the root, output every file that contained /folder/subfolder/ in its path.  Note the '?' marks are to compensate for case-sensitivity.

Comment: Use `-iname` instead of `-name` if the goal is case-insensitivity. Your example would match `Xolder/Jubfolder`, `6older/_ubfolder`, and more.

Comment: The `-name` primary only matches against the file name, not the entire path. For that, us `-path`...

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `find` with `grep`:

```
find | grep -i "\/folder\/subfolder\/"
```